# Lambda doesn't copy object to another bucket when delete object event triggers

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, botocore

Lambda below works just fine with the object create event triggers but doesn't copy object on delete object event. Turning versioning on (to switch to deletes with markers instead of permanent) doesn't change it. Lambda role has arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess and arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambda_FullAccess policies attached.
What is a problem with this function?

```
import json
import boto3

# boto3 S3 initialization
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")


def lambda_handler(event, context):
   

   source_bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
   destination_bucket_name = source_bucket_name + '-glacier'

   print(f'Copying from {source_bucket_name} to {destination_bucket_name}')
   print("Event :", event)

   # Filename of an object (with path)
   file_key_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

   # Copy Source Object
   copy_source_object = {'Bucket': source_bucket_name, 'Key': file_key_name}

   # S3 copy object operation
   s3_client.copy_object(CopySource=copy_source_object, Bucket=destination_bucket_name, Key=file_key_name, StorageClass='GLACIER')

   return {
       'statusCode': 200,
       'body': json.dumps('Hello from S3 events Lambda!')
   }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what objects you want to copy on delete event? Because if an object is deleted, how you can copy it?

Comment: @Marcin, these are just some text files which are backed up (copied to another bucket with Glacier storage class). Doesn't on delete trigger take place before the actual object deletion? Also, in case of enabled versioning object is not deleted but simply marked as delete and it should be possible to copy.

Comment: The event occurs after deletion. But off course when version object is deleted, delete marker is created. So you could access the object still, but your code does not seem to operate on any object versions.

Comment: @Marcin, thank you.

Comment: No problem. So if you wish to work with version objects you would have to modify your code.

Comment: Yeah, I will add a function to get the latest version before delete marker.